# How to save and then load a seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a seaborn jointplot

```
fig = sns.jointplot(x=[1,2,3,4],y=[4,3,2,1])
```

How do I save it and then load it back as an image inside databricks so I can use it in a subplot?

when I try to load the image back in from dbfs using mping.imread it tells me 'Jointgrid does not have an attribute imread'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the mentioned sample jointplot to save down and load back in using this code

Saving:

```
plot = sns.jointplot(x=[1,2,3,4],y=[4,3,2,1])
plot.savefig('/dbfs/FileStore/figure.png')
```

Loading:

```
img = plt.imread('/dbfs/FileStore/figure.png')
```

Displaying:

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

Hope this helped!

Edit:
Additionally I know you mentioned making it part of a subplot you can use this code to do that:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(25,16))
axarr[1,1].imshow(mpimg.imread(figname1))
axarr[2,1].imshow(mpimg.imread(figname2))
[ax.set_axis_off() for ax in axarr.ravel()]
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```